# Why there won't be a value pass in my modal body?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, modal-dialog

For example there are three inputed sample and when I try to delete the second inputed sample it won't be deleted instead the third one will be the one is deleted. Another error is that if there will be one inputed sample left and I try to delete it then code will be error.

Modal Code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

        <h1 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h1>
        </div>

       <form class ="delete" action="{{ action('ReservationController@destroy', ['id' => $reservation->id])}}" method="post">


        {{ method_field('DELETE')}}
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete?
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="reservation_id" id="resid" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">No, Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes, Delete</button>

        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script Code

```
<script>
    $('#delete').on('show.bs.modal',function(event){
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var resid = button.data('deleteid')
    var modal = $(this)

    modal.find('.modal-body #resid').val(resid)
    })
    </script>
```

Button code

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-deleteid="{{$reservation->id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" >Delete</button>
```

Controller

```
$reservation = PropertyReservation::findOrFail($id);
    $reservation->delete();

    return redirect('/reservations')->with('success','Successfully Deleted');
```

Comment: Can you show your route and more of the controller please?

Comment: for my route 
this is only the one i have for the reservation
Route::resource('residents', 'ResidentsController');

and for the controller thats all i have

Comment: `    $('#delete').on('show.bs.modal',function(event){` you are targeting wrong class??

Comment: what do you mean wrong targeting ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
$(document).on('show.bs.modal','#delete',function(event){
   var resid = $(this).find('button[type="submit"]').attr('data-deleteid')
   var modal = $(this);

   modal.find('.modal-body #resid').val(resid);
})
</script>
```